# CakePHP Model: COUNT(*) in Containable

Tags: php, cakephp, model, pagination

I have a CakePHP 1.3 app and really enjoy the [Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable) for fetching data.

Let's assume I have Posts in one-to-many relationship with Comments. I use Containable to query (for pagination) a list of all Posts and the belonging Comments. But I'm only interested in how many Comments each Post has. I did not found any way to achieve this query with containable without fetching all rows of Comments. I tried:

```
$this->paginate=array(
            'fields' => 'Post.title, Post.created',
            'contain' => array('Comment'=>'COUNT(*) AS count'),
        );
```

results in 'Model "Comment" is not associated with model "Count"' error message.

```
$this->paginate=array(
            'fields' => array('Post.title, Post.created'),
            'contain' => array('Comment'=>array('fields'=>'COUNT(*) AS count'),
        );
```

does not work, result set contains for each Post an empty Comment array except for the last one, where it contains the count field, but having the number of all comments not just the belonging ones.

My other guess was

```
$this->paginate=array(
            'fields' => 'Post.title, Post.created, COUNT(Comment.id)',
            'contain' => array('Comment'=>array('fields'=>''),
        );
```

but this results in an error, because hasMany relationships are queried independently, so the Answer table is not in the query for the Post entries.
How can I count the number of Comments a Post has?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution without the counterCache?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the best way to do this is to set up a field called `comment_count` in the `posts` table and add this key to the Comment model $belongsTo Post array:

`'counterCache' => true`

Every time anything will be happening with the comments, the comment_count field in the related post will be updated (actually, it recounts every time, instead of just adding or deleting).

It's better, because when you fetch data for the user, its way faster and doesn't even touch the comments table. Since you're using the Containable behaviour I guess speed and lightweight is what you're looking for.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it doesn't solve the problem for more complex queries where keeping a count associated with a row wouldn't work (for example a reporting system where certain conditions are chosen by the user). Is there no other way to get a count using containable?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question.  The answer that PawelMysior gave was great and lead to the solution.

I found some more details in the CakePHP Book: [3.7.4.1.1 counterCache - Cache your count()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count). This was helpful but still a bit vague.  For the sake of others, I want to provide some further details.

I have two tables: Post and Image.  When I added an image to a post I want to keep track of how many images each post had for display on the Post index list, without needing to run an extra count query on the Image table.

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(255),
body TEXT,
created DATETIME,
modified DATETIME,
image_count INTEGER UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE images
(
id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
post_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
filename VARCHAR(255),
created DATETIME,
modified DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Notice that the `image_count` goes in the `posts` table.  Nothing special is needed in the `images` table.

```
class Post extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Memory';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Image' => array(
            'className' => 'Image',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );
}

class Image extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Image';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
            'counterCache' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Notice that `counterCache` is added to the `Image` model.  Nothing special is needed in the `Post` model.

```
$this->Post->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$post = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('user_id' => 7),
    'order' => array('Post.created DESC'),
    'contain' => array(
        'Post' => array(
            'User' => array('first_name', 'last_name')
        )
    )
));
```

Now when we do a `find` there is no need to do anything special to find the count because it is automatically a field in the `Post` results.  Notice the `image_count` below.

```
Array
(
[Post] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [user_id] => 7
                    [title] => Another great post
                    [body] => Lorem ipsum...
                    [created] => 2011-10-26 11:45:05
                    [modified] => 2011-10-26 11:45:05
                    [image_count] => 21
                    [User] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => John
                        [last_name] => Doe
                    )
                )
        )
)
```

One thing to note, if you add counterCache to an existing database structure, the counts in `Post` will be zero until another `Image` is added.  At the point, CakePHP will do an actual count and update the `image_count` to the correct amount.

I hope this extra information is helpful for someone.

Comment: I noticed that someone downvoted this but did not leave a comment as to why. Maybe it has to do with this question/answer being 8 years old? Either way, a downvote without a comment is bad form.