# CakePHP 2.x GROUP BY within Containable

Tags: php, cakephp, lamp, cakephp-2.x

I am going nuts trying to find a good solution, either using the `set::extract()` or something. I want to add a GROUP BY within my containable:

```
$params = array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Project.id'=>$ProjectId
    ),
    'contain'=>array(
        //Gets the User Who owns the Project
        'User'=>$user,
        'Bid'=>array(
            //The User Who owns the Bid
            'User'=>$user
        ),
        'ProjectType',
        'Os',
        'Comment'=>array(
            'To'=>$user,
            'From'=>$user,
            'group'=>"Comment.from_id"
        ),
    ),
);
//debug($params);
return $this->find('first',$params);
```

I do not want to hack to get around this issue - is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: How exactly do you want to retrieve the Comment's? I don't see an aggregate column, so I don't know why you would need to group in the first place (also you really can't group on just that one field in your case). So what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: For those who wish to use group by in order to perform a count, there is an efficient workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2308087/1836940

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else that stumbles on this via Google, it looks as though `GROUP BY` conditions for containable queries [aren't supported in Cake 1 or 2](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/1759), so a manual join would be required if grouping is a must.

Comment: ["Seems to be resolved with 3.0"](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/1759#issuecomment-31795002)

Answer (score -1):

You can do conditions within contained items:

```
'contain'=>array(
    'Comment'=>array(
        'To'=>$user,
        'From'=>$user,
        'conditions'=>array(
            'group'=>"Comment.from_id"
        ),
     ),
)
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

Comment: group is not a condition