# Cakephp count containable records

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Cakephp 2.6

Schools hasMany Pupils and I am running a containable query from the Schools model. In this query I want to count the number of pupils each school has but I can't get it to work.

I've tried using the following virtual field, but it doesn't work

`$this->virtualFields['total'] = 'COUNT(Pupil.id)';`
and the following is giving inaccurate counts

```
$contain = array(
            'Pupil' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'CONT(Pupil.id) AS total'
                )
            ),
        );
```

I don't want to use `counterCache` as data can be mass imported to both tables outside of the framework so I can't rely on it to update the count field.
How can I get this count to run correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add grouping by `School`s:

```
    $contain = array(
        'Pupil' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'CONT(Pupil.id) AS total'
            ),
            'group' => array('Pupil.school_id') // doesn't really know how you called `school` relation column...
        ),
    );
```

Comment: It gives an error now `Model Pupil is not associated with model Pupil`

Comment: Oh, looks like Cake 2 doesn't supports groupping... Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970873/cakephp-group-by-within-containable) for more info

Comment: I've tried a manual join and I can't get it to work either. How would I construct it properly?