# count rows where product.store_id = store.id from product table HABM association

Tags: mysql, cakephp, contain

I'm trying to get total no of products from products table where product.store_id = store.id in cakephp to shoq store owner his total products in his store and i'm using containable behavior to get this by this query

```
 $stores = $this->Store->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
           'Product' => array(
           'conditions' => array('product.store_id = store.id')
          'fields' => array('COUNT(*) AS count')
        ) 
)));
```

Store HABM products
product HABM Store

3 tables

stores
products
products_stores

But i'm getting empty array of products on view

```
[Product] => Array
                (
                )
```

i know ,i'm not getting product(id, name, other features), but total no of products should be in this array. 
Or kindly tell me the way to get total products of specific store.

sorry for bad English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP Model: COUNT(\*) in Containable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308087/cakephp-model-count-in-containable)

Comment: i saw that before post my question.  i tried to do in that way but my problem was not solved.let me do one more try to do in that way.

Comment: @bish  that is for hasMAny association , but i have HABM association Products HABM Stores and Stres HABM Products, so in this way i found a way to add countercache var $actsAs = array('CounterCacheHabtm');   but my store model already has public $actsAs = array('Containable');  so what you say now

Comment: Use both: `$actsAS =  array('Containable','CounterCacheHabtm');`